# Python: Non-modal window with subprocesses

Tags: python, multithreading, qt, non-modal

I need to implement the following UI:
- There is a window with a label "running experiment 1/X" and a button
- When the window is loaded, some experiments are started. The experiments are run by `os.system` of `subprocess.Popen`, they are just pre-compiled C++ programs
- The experiments should run strictly one after another and not simultaneously (hence I can't use `subprocess.Popen`)
- The window should be active while the experiments are running and the user can press the button
- When the button is pressed, the experiments stop (we can just wait until the current experiment ends and stop) and the window closes
- When all experiments are over, the window should close itself

First I tried running experiments in `threading.Thread`, but it still blocked the window. So I switched to `multiprocessing.Process`:

```
class StoppableProcess(Process):
    def __init__(self, name, alg, proj, parent):
        Process.__init__(self)
        self.stop = False
        self.name = name
        self.alg = alg
        self.proj = proj
        self.parent = parent 

    def stop(self):
        self.stop = True

    def stopped(self):
        return self.stop

    def run(self):
        count = len([k for k in self.proj.values()])
        i = 1
        for p in self.proj.values():
            self.parent.label.setText("Running experiment " + str(i) + " / " + str(count))
            os.system("some command here")
            i += 1
            if self.stopped():
                break  
        self.parent.hide() 



class Runner(QDialog):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        QDialog.__init__(self, parent)
        self.layout = QVBoxLayout()
        self.label = QLabel("Running experiment 0 / 0")
        self.setWindowTitle("Running experiments")
        button = QPushButton("Break experiments")
        self.layout.addWidget(self.label)
        self.layout.addWidget(button)
        self.setLayout(self.layout)
        QObject.connect(button, SIGNAL("clicked()"), self.Break)

    def Run(self, name, alg, proj):
        self.thread = StoppableProcess(name, alg, proj, self)
        self.thread.start()
        self.show()
        self.thread.join()

    def Break(self):
        self.thread.stop()
        self.hide()
```

However, this doesn't work at all, apparently because the `Runner` object should be pickled to be passed to a subprocess, but pickling fails. I was thinking about avoiding passing the parent argument and using Qt signals instead, but maybe there's a better solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, you can indeed use `subprocess.Popen` to start background processes and wait for their completion. See the [documentation](http://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html), specifically, the `poll()` method. Run the UI event loop until the process has exited.

Second, it is usually a good idea to avoid threads in Python. The multiprocessing module is mostly useful when you want to parallelize tasks written in Python. IMO, I think it is easier to use the subprocess module if you are just launching external child processes.

The following pseudocode illustrates the idea:

```
experiments = [...]
process = None

def start_next_experiment():
    if not experiments:
        print "Done!"
    else:
        experiment = experiments.pop()
        process = subprocess.Popen(experiment)

def on_start_clicked():
    start_next_experiment()

def on_stop_clicked():
     # Clear the queue
    experiments = []

    # optional: Kill the process
    if process:
        process.terminate()

def on_idle():
    if process:
        # use e.g. a PyQT timer to run this method periodically
        process.poll()
        if process.returncode is not None:
            process = None
            start_next_experiment()
```